UICollectionView DataSourcePrefetching: collectionView:prefetchItemsAtIndexPaths: not being called for subsequent row on initial load in UIKit
I am trying to emulate a Instagram stories full-screen horizontal pager collection view as follows:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    // Note: I set the frame for the collection view self.view.bounds later
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
    // ... other collection view configuration
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    ...
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    print(indexPaths)
}

This code works fine for every subsequent "page" after I scroll once, but it doesn't actually call the prefetch method on the initial load of the first cell.
Effectively, the actual output is:
[[2, 0]]
[[3, 0]]
[[4, 0]]
[[5, 0]]

but I would expect/desire it to be
[[1, 0]]
[[2, 0]]
[[3, 0]]
[[4, 0]]
[[5, 0]]

Is there a way to trigger this initial prefetch?

You need to fetch your initial content.  Prefetch is to prepare off-screen content in advance.

@flanker the issue is that the indexpath [1,0] is not being pre-fetched. It will only pre-fetch [2,0] and beyond index paths after I have paged/scrolled once.

yes, that's what pre-fetching does.  You will need to fetch the initial cell(s) directly.

The initial cell is for indexPath [0,0] not [1,0]. My expectation is that [1,0] should be called for prefetch while [0,0] is on-screen.
